# clamping the amplitude of a wave to certain level

Tags: diode-clamp, voltage-clipping, clamp

[image]

I'm trying to prevent a wave form from exceeding 10V.p.p.

I tried various things, but ... what the correct way to do it?

[image]

this clamps a 11V signal to +/- 900 mV ... and converts a triangle to square.

[image]
this works

Comment: I think you'd want to reference your AC signal on ground (or 0V), and likewise reference the 5V zener's that do the clipping also to ground

Comment: @PeteW, thank you, updated with new image, but still not the desired thing.

Comment: The 2nd figure is close, but put the 2 zeners in series.

Comment: @Mattman944, Thnx, i replaced the zeners with normal 1n4148 and 5V negative / positive voltages on them. it works.

Comment: In your second picture, the zeners just act like ordinary diodes.  That's why your seeing a +/-900 mV swing.

Comment: @SteveSh Thnx, i updated with new pic, that's how i started out. but without the second capacitor at the end. but this works.

Comment: @SteveSh putting back the zeners gives undesired result, using Falstad.com simulator.

Comment: @SteveSh, now the question is if the second capacitor at the end is correctly oriented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A four diode clipper is probably a friendlier way to clip an audio signal since the input impedance doesn't change as much as the two diode clipper. One drawback is the dynamic resistance of the diodes changes with input level which will increase distortion during the unclipped periods. I like the idea of this clipper since it's a creative way to use diodes.

[image: clipper 4-diode]

The red trace is the input impedance.

Comment: Thank you, got it working ... dynamic resistance?

Comment: Unless distortion (when not clipping) is not important you'd be better to use a rail-rail FET op-amp with the positive and negative supply set to your clipping level. Here's a single ended example: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/491680/precision-voltage-clamping-0v-to-5v-with-12v-input/491687#491687  ...you just need to use the +/- supply lines you indicate you have.

Comment: @JackCreasey, i know how to solve it with a Rail 2 Rail opamp, but my "dealer" does not have them in his assortment, i have the mcp6002/4 here, that's a 6 V model (VDD – VSS range = 7.0V) witch model would you suggest that could be a "replacement" for the TL072 and have this "±2.25 V to ±20 V, 4.5 V to 40 V" operating range, slew. i'm not familiar with a rail 2 rail opamp that equally famous as the TL072 / TL074 and have them in DIP / DIL variants.

Comment: @JackCreasey, would schottky diode's be a better choise? how about the 1K resitors ... if using zener diodes for a supply.

Comment: @NaturalDemon, the diodes don't make a difference other than their Vf slope will change the distortion slop.